How to check whether a character was rendered correctly?
I am building an online Chinese dictionary in Flutter. The app contains some uncommon characters that can not be rendered and show tofu instead.
Is there a way to detect these characters? It would be nice to add an explanation or further instructions if the user bumps into one of them.

I consider that you should take good use of the attribute of TextStyle -- fontFamily on all of the widgets which display texts, such as Text, RichText, TextField and etc.. And make sure of the font file includes Chinese characters as many as possible.
Here are some awesome fonts that should satisfies your needs, you can get and use them for free: https://hyperos.mi.com/font/zh/.
